# User submitted post

Tags: posts, users

I'm sure there are plugins to do this but I wanted to try and do it myself.

I have a form that contains a title and a content/message area.

I would like to add this form as a post when fill it in.

How do I go about adding the user completed form as a post.

Any tutorials or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that requests for off-site resources like tutorials is explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your form, submit it to `PHP_SELF`, [sanatize your data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and finally run your data through [`wp_insert_post() Function`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). You should be able to research everything else to achieve what you're looking for but this will get you started. Good luck!